# How to convert to big endian in ruby

Tags: ruby, endianness

I have a string in little-endian order, as a hexadecimal-encoded string

```
000000020597ba1f0cd423b2a3abb0259a54ee5f783077a4ad45fb6200000218
000000008348d1339e6797e2b15e9a3f2fb7da08768e99f02727e4227e02903e
43a42b31511553101a051f3c0000000000000080000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080020000
```

I'd like to byteswap each 32-bit chunk from little-endian to big-endian resulting to

```
020000001fba9705b223d40c25b0aba35fee549aa477307862fb45ad18020000
0000000033d14883e297679e3f9a5eb108dab72ff0998e7622e427273e90027e
312ba443105315513c1f051a0000000080000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280
```

I've tried several approaches but haven't goten it to work. It'd be great if someone can show a sample implementation.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `pack` and `unpack` by:

- first going decoding the hexadecimal
- then converting to 32 bit integers in small endian
- encoding these integers with big endian
- encoding the result in hexadecimal.

In code:

```
s = "000000020597ba1f0cd4..."
[s].pack('H*').unpack('N*').pack('V*').unpack('H*')
# => "020000001fba9705b223..."
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Łukasz Niemier's answer, you can let `scan` handle the grouping in one step:

```
hex_string = "000000020597ba1f..."
hex_string.scan(/(..)(..)(..)(..)/).map(&:reverse).join
# => "020000001fba9705..."
```

- `scan(/(..)(..)(..)(..)/)` splits the string into groups of 4 x 2 bytes:

  ```
  [["00", "00", "00", "02"], ["05", "97", "ba", "1f"], ... ]
  ```
- `map(&:reverse)` reverses the inner 2-byte arrays:

  ```
  [["02", "00", "00", "00"], ["1f", "ba", "97", "05"], ... ]
  ```
- `join` joins all array elements

  ```
  "020000001fba9705..."
  ```

Comment: Or even better `/(..){4}/`.

Comment: I see. IMHO it's a bug, but I will check it after I return.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is to split string for each 8 characters:

```
hexes = str.scan(/.{8}/)
```

then map them to change endiannes by reversing each 2 chars:

```
big = hexes.map { |hex| hex.scan(/.{2}/).reverse.join('') }
```

and then join them all together

```
str = big.join('')
```

Pry session example:

```
[23] pry(main)> str
=> "000000020597ba1f0cd423b2a3abb0259a54ee5f783077a4ad45fb6200000218000000008348d1339e6797e2b15e9a3f2fb7da08768e99f02727e4227e02903e43a42b31511553101a051f3c00000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080020000"
[24] pry(main)> str.scan(/.{8}/).map { |s| s.scan(/.{2}/).reverse.join('') }.join('')
=> "020000001fba9705b223d40c25b0aba35fee549aa477307862fb45ad180200000000000033d14883e297679e3f9a5eb108dab72ff0998e7622e427273e90027e312ba443105315513c1f051a00000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280"
```

<strike>Or improving @Stefan's answer:</strike>

```
hex_string.scan(/(..){4}/).msp(&:reverse).join('') # remember that anybody can change $, variable
```